# Spark : Is there differences between agg function and a window function on a spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I want to apply a sum on a column in spark Dataframe (Spark 2.1). I have two ways to do that:

1- With a Window function:

```scala
val windowing = Window.partitionBy("id")
dataframe
.withColumn("sum", sum(col("column_1")) over windowing)
```

2- With the agg function:

```scala
dataframe
.groupBy("id")
.agg(sum(col("column_1")).alias("sum"))
```

What is the best way to do that in term of performances? And what's the differences between these two methods?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use aggregation functions both within a window (your first case), or when grouping (your second case). The difference is that with a window, each **row** will be associated with the result of the aggregation computed on its entire window. When grouping however, each **group** will be associated with the result of the aggregation on that group (a group of rows becomes only one row).

In your situation, you would get this.

```scala
val dataframe = spark.range(6).withColumn("key", 'id % 2)
dataframe.show
+---+---+
| id|key|
+---+---+
|  0|  0|
|  1|  1|
|  2|  0|
|  3|  1|
|  4|  0|
|  5|  1|
+---+---+
```

**Case 1: windowing**

```scala
val windowing = Window.partitionBy("key")
dataframe.withColumn("sum", sum(col("id")) over windowing).show
+---+---+---+                                                                   
| id|key|sum|
+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|  6|
|  2|  0|  6|
|  4|  0|  6|
|  1|  1|  9|
|  3|  1|  9|
|  5|  1|  9|
+---+---+---+
```

**Case 2: grouping**

```scala
dataframe.groupBy("key").agg(sum('id)).show
+---+-------+
|key|sum(id)|
+---+-------+
|  0|      6|
|  1|      9|
+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Oli mentioned aggregation functions can be used within a window (first case) as well as with grouping (second case).  In term of performance,  'aggregation function with grouping' will be much faster in comparision to 'aggregation function with Window'. we can visualize this by analyzing the Physical plan.

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(sum($"expense").alias("total_expense")).explain()
df.show
+---+----------+                                                                   
|  id|  expense|
+---+----------+
|   1|      100|
|   2|      300|
|   1|      100|
|   3|      200|
+---+----------+
```

1- Aggregation with Window :

```
df.withColumn("total_expense", sum(col("expense")) over window).show
+---+----------+-------------------+                                                     
| id|   expense|      total_expense|
+---+----------+-------------------+
|  3|       200|                200|
|  1|       100|                200|
|  1|       100|                200|
|  2|       300|                300|
+---+----------+-------------------+

df.withColumn("total_expense", sum(col("expense")) over window).explain
== Physical Plan ==
Window [sum(cast(expense#9 as bigint)) windowspecdefinition(id#8, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS total_expense#265L], [id#8]
+- *(2) Sort [id#8 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#8, 200), true, [id=#144]
      +- *(1) Project [_1#3 AS id#8, _2#4 AS expense#9]
         +- *(1) SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, knownnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._1, true, false) AS _1#3, knownnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._2 AS _2#4]
            +- Scan[obj#2]
```

2- Aggregation with GroupBy :

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(sum($"expense").alias("total_expense")).show
+---+------------------+                                                             
| id|     total_expense|
+---+------------------+
|  3|               200|
|  1|               200|
|  2|               300|
+---+------------------+

df.groupBy("id").agg(sum($"expense").alias("total_expense")).explain()
    == Physical Plan ==
    *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[id#8], functions=[sum(cast(expense#9 as bigint))])
    +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#8, 200), true, [id=#44]
       +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[id#8], functions=[partial_sum(cast(expense#9 as bigint))])
          +- *(1) Project [_1#3 AS id#8, _2#4 AS expense#9]
             +- *(1) SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, knownnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._1, true, false) AS _1#3, knownnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._2 AS _2#4]
                +- Scan[obj#2]
```

Based on execution plan we can see in case of windows there is one total shuffle and one sort whereas in case of groupby there is one **reduced** shuffle (shuffle after local aggregate partial_sum).

Comment: window: sort + scan, groupBy: scan..is this the difference you're highlighting?